# I did changed the text of a graphical text and set its new center origin. Should I reposition it in dead center again?

Tags: sfml, position

Should I re-position a graphical text in the dead center again, which I previously do, after editing the text of the graphical text, recalculate its new center origin of the text? I did see that with a new origin, the text automatically applied to whatever the previous x and y were. Does it a wasteful thing to add another duplicate line of code to set it in the dead center?

I saw this sample code from a book. It's confusing for beginners without any explanation for it. Why had the author added that line of code? It's dead center anyway without it.

```
// Draw some text
Text messageText;

// Assign the actual message
messageText.setString("Press Enter to start!");

// Position the text
FloatRect textRect = messageText.getLocalBounds();

messageText.setOrigin(textRect.left +
    textRect.width / 2.0f,
    textRect.top +
    textRect.height / 2.0f);
    
messageText.setPosition(1920 / 2.0f, 1080 / 2.0f);

// has the player been squished by a branch?
if (branchPositions[5] == playerSide)
{
    // Change the text of the message
    messageText.setString("SQUISHED!!");

    // Center it on the screen
    FloatRect textRect = messageText.getLocalBounds();
    messageText.setOrigin(textRect.left +
        textRect.width / 2.0f,
        textRect.top +
        textRect.height / 2.0f);

    messageText.setPosition(1920 / 2.0f, 1080 / 2.0f);  // Should I add do this line of code? 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right; in this short example, the call is not needed.

However, consider this: what if you kept adding code between those two calls? what if you reused the same text object for different contexts? what if instead of reusing the same text object, you would create a new one for this new context?

Your future self would likely be happy to see that call there, just as a reminder that 1) it is actually set and 2) where it is positioning the object.

So although it is not *needed*, it is a good habit to place it there, right after you've set the new size and/or origin. The cost of this call is insignificant.

I suppose some experienced developers (the kind of devs that write books) 1) don't necessarily reflect on all those subtleties that experience brings and 2) don't think about writing it in their books.

Comment: Those last couple of points are excelllent observations. Additionally, some books are constrained by page count & layout limitations.